# How to change TimePicker's RadialTimePickerView's background color in Lollipop?

Tags: android-timepicker

I have asked a question concerning the DatePicker's CalendarView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170874/how-to-change-datepickers-calendarviews-background-color-in-lollipop/29175115#29175115), and alanv's solution works very well with DatePicker's. However, when I tried his solution in TimePicker's, it doesn't work that way.

[image]

I want to change the text color of inside the clock. Similar to my last question, I tried adding color accent. To ensure it would work, I added textColor as well.

The 
v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTimePickerTheme" >
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/myColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/myTextColor</item>
</style>
```

However, It does work like DatePicker, any suggestion?