# Android API 21+ DatePicker Can't Hide Fields

Tags: android, datepicker, show-hide, android-api-levels

I'm trying to show only day of month and month fields in DatePicker in AlertDialog. On previous API's from API 21, i can do it with code below.But when i try to do it in API21+ "getDeclaredFields()" doesn't even returns like "mYearPicker" or "mYearSpinner" fields.Does anyone have any idea how can i just show Day and Month fields?And i don't even know what field "116" is.

My code like this:

```
 final DatePicker datePickerStart = new DatePicker(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar));
    datePickerStart .setCalendarViewShown(false);
    datePickerStart .setSpinnersShown(true);
    try {
        Field f[] = datePickerStart .getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : f) {
            if (field.getName().equals("mYearPicker")|| field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object yearPicker = new Object();
                yearPicker = field.get(datePickerStart);
                ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Should look like:
[Before API 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBxaV.png)

Looks like this:
[API 21+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bH8T.png)

Any idea?

Comment: Um, why not fork `DatePicker` and modify it to suit? Or, why not use [a third-party library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/27)? What makes you think that this approach will work across thousands of Android device models, given that device manufacturers can change Android internals, let alone Google with new Android versions?

Comment: seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789907/hide-day-month-or-year-from-datepicker-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: @Morse thanks!! it worked well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Morse i found the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32902464/5019811)

```
public DatePicker initMonthPicker(){
    DatePicker dp_mes = new DatePicker(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar));

    int year    = dp_mes.getYear();
    int month   = dp_mes.getMonth();
    int day     = dp_mes.getDayOfMonth();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int daySpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android");
        if (daySpinnerId != 0)
        {
            View daySpinner = dp_mes.findViewById(daySpinnerId);
            if (daySpinner != null)
            {
                daySpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        int monthSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android");
        if (monthSpinnerId != 0)
        {
            View monthSpinner = dp_mes.findViewById(monthSpinnerId);
            if (monthSpinner != null)
            {
                monthSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        int yearSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android");
        if (yearSpinnerId != 0)
        {
            View yearSpinner = dp_mes.findViewById(yearSpinnerId);
            if (yearSpinner != null)
            {
                yearSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    } else { //Older SDK versions
        Field f[] = dp_mes.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : f)
        {
            if(field.getName().equals("mDayPicker") || field.getName().equals("mDaySpinner"))
            {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object dayPicker = null;
                try {
                    dayPicker = field.get(dp_mes);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if(field.getName().equals("mMonthPicker") || field.getName().equals("mMonthSpinner"))
            {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object monthPicker = null;
                try {
                    monthPicker = field.get(dp_mes);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((View) monthPicker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if(field.getName().equals("mYearPicker") || field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner"))
            {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object yearPicker = null;
                try {
                    yearPicker = field.get(dp_mes);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    return dp_mes;
}
```

So i just call this method when i need for a new DatePicker object