# Only select date in datePicker

Tags: android, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

> Is it possible to allow datePicker only display date and hide year and
>   month ?

I have two activities, in Activity A, I have datePicker which only display month and year. In Activity B, I want datePicker display only date, but can't find any solutions from internet.

**ScreenShot of Activity A**

[image]

Assume user select **Jun 2018**. Then in **Activity B**, the datePicker will show Jun 2018 as the dialog title and only allow user to select the date.

**Activity B**

```
   month = getIntent().getStringExtra("month"); // Jun 2018

    date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });

     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListner = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {

                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = this.customDatePicker();
                    return datePickerDialog;
            }
            return null;
        }

private DatePickerDialog customDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListner,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        try {
            Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
                if ((datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mYearPicker"))||(datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mMonthPicker"))) {
                    datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField
                            .get(dpd);
                    Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType()
                            .getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                        if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())
                                || "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField
                                .getName())) {
                            datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                            Object dayPicker = new Object();
                            dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return dpd;
    }
```

Comment: you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32902464/1790537

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        try {
            Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
                if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {

                    datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField
                            .get(dpd);
                    Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType()
                            .getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                        if ("mYearPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())
                                || "mYearSpinner".equals(datePickerField
                                .getName()||"mMonthPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())||"mMonthSpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                            datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                            Object dayPicker = new Object();
                            dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I getting date,year and month

Comment: check my post again. Thanks

Comment: I understand bro. I disable month and year  here ..          ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Give me some time

Comment: @JohnJoe please see