# Android: Hide DatePicker header (selected day, month and year)

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-6.0-marshmallow

I was trying to create a CalendarView in Lollipop when I ran it I didn't get the same design as Marshmallow so I changed to DatePicker but I don't want the header part just the Calendar. Is that possible?

I have tried this code in my MainActivity but with no luck (referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789907/hide-day-month-or-year-from-datepicker-in-android-5-0-lollipop/32902464#32902464)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initMonthPicker();
}
public void initMonthPicker() {
    DatePicker dp_mes = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);

    int year = dp_mes.getYear();
    int month = dp_mes.getMonth();
    int day = dp_mes.getDayOfMonth();
    dp_mes.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            int month_i = monthOfYear + 1;
            Log.e("selected month:", Integer.toString(month_i));
            //Add whatever you need to handle Date changes
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int daySpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android");
        if (daySpinnerId != 0) {
            View daySpinner = dp_mes.findViewById(daySpinnerId);
            if (daySpinner != null) {
                daySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        int monthSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android");
        if (monthSpinnerId != 0) {
            View monthSpinner = dp_mes.findViewById(monthSpinnerId);
            if (monthSpinner != null) {
                monthSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        int yearSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android");
        if (yearSpinnerId != 0) {
            View yearSpinner = dp_mes.findViewById(yearSpinnerId);
            if (yearSpinner != null) {
                yearSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    } else { //Older SDK versions
        Field f[] = dp_mes.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : f) {
            if (field.getName().equals("mDayPicker") || field.getName().equals("mDaySpinner")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object dayPicker = null;
                try {
                    dayPicker = field.get(dp_mes);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (field.getName().equals("mMonthPicker") || field.getName().equals("mMonthSpinner")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object monthPicker = null;
                try {
                    monthPicker = field.get(dp_mes);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((View) monthPicker).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (field.getName().equals("mYearPicker") || field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner")) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object yearPicker = null;
                try {
                    yearPicker = field.get(dp_mes);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.calendarviewtest.MainActivity">


    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?